# Windows Phone app w/Phonegap - in app browser not working in store version

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I have the simplest windows phone phonegap app set up. I downloaded phonegap from github, set up the project templates, and created a new project in VS Express. I then went into www/index.html and changed it to the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body><a href="http://www.cnn.com">Test Link</a>
</html>
```

I then deployed the application to a device and it worked fine. It was a blank white screen with "Test Link" at the top, if I click on "Test Link" I am correctly taken to cnn.com. However, the problem occurs when I submit the app to the Windows Phone Store. I have tried numerous times to beta release my app. The process goes fine, I download the app, run the app and I see "Test Link". But when I click the link I get a

```
We can't display this page right now. 

The website you're trying to reach may be experiencing technical difficulties. Try again later. 

Error: Cannot find server or DNS error
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by setting the following capability in the WMAppManifest.xml file

```
ID_CAP_NETWORKING
```